# Как изменить отображение определённых символов?

Tags: vim

Есть ли способ заставить *Vim* отображать определённые символы
вместо других?  Например, я хочу, чтобы символ
`U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE` отображался не как  
(неотличимо от обычного пробела), а как `⍽`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как раз для неразрывного пробела можно установить опцию
[`listchars`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27listchars%27):

```vim
:set list listchars=nbsp:⍽
```

Это будет работать для символов `U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE`
и `U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE`.  Общего механизма для любых
символов, к сожалению, пока не нашёл.